# Allegro - implicit conversion loses integer precision - Warning on Xcode "fmaths.inl" interrupting some codes to work?

Tags: xcode, macos, allegro5

I'm trying to use allegro on Xcode, after following tutorials, i got this warning "implicit conversion loses integer precision".
I believe that i'm not able to make the game fullscreen or neither change the size of the screen because of this warning. I am not able to create bitmap of an image too

How would I fix this? I cannot make any changes to it as i have no permission at all!

```
int res = lres >> 16;
               ^            implicit conversion loses integer precision
```

Do help me out here

Comment: What is the type of lres?

Comment: Is it an error or a warning?  Warnings can be simply ignored.

Comment: Warning, but i had other problems like bitmap images not appearing, screen size are not able to change (it is always fixed). I would want to confirm that this warning is not causing the problem

Comment: The warning is *very unlikely* to indicate a real problem, but could in weird situations.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
NSInteger res = lres >> 16;
```

Comment: Use of undeclared identifier 'NSUInteger', Use of undeclared 'res', did you mean 'lres'?, and the same warning mention above "implicit conversion loses integer precision"

Comment: Tried that again, it gave me the same error "Use of undeclared identifier 'NSInteger'

Comment: I have tried NSUInteger and NSInteger both in sample OSX project and it does not give me any error.

Comment: for 64 bit machine int is not sufficient to hold all NSInteger's value. That's what make this warning appear.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33909/discussion-between-mihir-mehta-and-junyi00)